# Connecting to Azure in Server Explorer gives me value cannot be null, Parameter name: accountKey

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Hoping someone can help me out here.  I'm trying to connect to my notification hubs within Azure.  I've always been able to do it fine, until today.  Now every time I try to connect it tells me that I have no subscription.  (Which I do).

When I try to refresh the Notification Hubs portion is when I get the "value cannot be null" Parameter name: accountKey error.

I've tried two of my working Azure subscriptions with the same result.
I've tried restarting Visual Studio.
I've tried restarting my machine.

No luck.

Please help!  I really need to connect to Azure from the IDE for Notification Hubs because its the only easy way I get a visual list of all my devices registered.

Comment: So far it appears that I am getting this error because my Azure subscription was disabled because I exceeded our spending limit.  I have another account which has not exceeded its spending limit however and I'm still unable to access that account in Visual Studio either.  Any ideas?  I'll report back once I find out more...

Comment: Did you figure out a solution ?

Comment: @Mik yes I figured it out, just posted an answer, maybe it will work for you too, if not msg me back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it will fix it for you but it did for me:

I realized at some point that I wasn't logged in with an account to Visual Studio.  (Visual Studio encourages a login, but I don't believe enforces it).

Once I logged back in to Visual Studio with my MSN Id and removed the subscriptions and re-added them, it seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: I was logged in to Visual Studio with another account, also used for Azure services, and with wich everything works well. I logged out, changed my account to the new one, and it worked too ! I changed back my VS account to the original one, and this time I could connect to each account. Maybe it needed some sort of initialisation? Thank anyway, and please mark as answer !

Answer (score 0):

I re-added my subscription account and it fixed the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).